# RestAPI and Front end in the same domain

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, intellij-idea

I am building a restful api in Java using Jersey (Intellij Idea with the WebServices option). The webservice returns geolocation in JSON. This works well.

I have a front end using Google Maps API. It needs to receive the location from my API and display it. The front end is also ready.

Now, since both were developed independently, I run into Cross Domain authentication issues. I know I can solve these by using filters and all, but that is not the solution I want. How can I have the front end to be part of the same domain. For instance path1 (/getData) would give me json and path2 (/index.html) will give me the visualization.

I am not using any MVC patthern. Should I switch to Spring MVC? If I don't what are my options?

Also, generally, how does a front end in a project interact with the backend in the SAME project? Is it pure REST calls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Play MVC which provides both visualization as well as REST API interface. https://www.playframework.com/